# Forestplot in R superscript in tabletext matrix

Tags: r, superscript, r-forestplot

I am creating a forestplot in R. Since I cannot display my own data I am using example code and data that I found here
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forestplot/vignettes/forestplot.html

```
cochrane_from_rmeta <- 
structure(list(
mean  = c(NA, NA, 0.578, 0.165, 0.246, 0.700, 0.348, 0.139, 1.017, NA, 0.531), 
lower = c(NA, NA, 0.372, 0.018, 0.072, 0.333, 0.083, 0.016, 0.365, NA, 0.386),
upper = c(NA, NA, 0.898, 1.517, 0.833, 1.474, 1.455, 1.209, 2.831, NA, 0.731)),
.Names = c("mean", "lower", "upper"), 
row.names = c(NA, -11L), 
class = "data.frame")


tabletext<-cbind(
c("", "Study", "Auckland", "Block", 
"Doran", "Gamsu", "Morrison", "Papageorgiou", 
"Tauesch", NA, "Summary"),
c("Deaths", "(steroid)", "36", "1", 
"4", "14", "3", "1", 
"8", NA, NA),
c("Deaths", "(placebo)", "60", "5", 
"11", "20", "7", "7", 
"10", NA, NA),
c("", "OR", "0.58", "0.16", 
"0.25", "0.70", "0.35", "0.14", 
"1.02", NA, "0.53"),
c("",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"Heterogeniety I^2 = 20%"))[enter image description here][1]


library(forestplot)
 forestplot(tabletext, 
       cochrane_from_rmeta,new_page = TRUE,
       is.summary=c(TRUE,TRUE,rep(FALSE,8),TRUE),
       clip=c(0.1,2.5), 
       xlog=TRUE, 
       col=fpColors(box="royalblue",line="darkblue", summary="royalblue"))
```

I would like to superscript the very last label for Heterogeniety. I tried expression(Heterogeniety~I^2), but I get the following error message:

Error in cbind(c("Outcome", "Death or BPD", NA, NA, NA, "Interaction p value = .xx",  : cannot create a matrix from type 'expression'

How do I include a superscript in my forestplot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R does not allow you to create a matrix of expression. Also mentioned in the documentation for `forestplot`,

> > You can also provide a matrix although this cannot have expressions by design

Luckily, the documentation for `forestplot` also mentioned that it can take in a list for `labeltext`.

> > The list should be wrapped in m x n number to resemble a matrix: list(list("rowname 1 col 1", "rowname 2 col 1"), list("r1c2", expression(beta))

Hence, you might want to convert your `tabletext` into a nested list as follows:

```
tabletext <- list(
    list("", "Study", "Auckland", "Block", 
        "Doran", "Gamsu", "Morrison", "Papageorgiou", 
        "Tauesch", NA, "Summary"),
    list("Deaths", "(steroid)", "36", "1", 
        "4", "14", "3", "1", 
        "8", NA, NA),
    list("Deaths", "(placebo)", "60", "5", 
        "11", "20", "7", "7", 
        "10", NA, NA),
    list("", "OR", "0.58", "0.16", 
        "0.25", "0.70", "0.35", "0.14", 
        "1.02", NA, "0.53"),
    list("",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, expression(Heterogeniety~I^2==20~'%')))


forestplot(tabletext, 
    cochrane_from_rmeta,new_page = TRUE,
    is.summary=c(TRUE,TRUE,rep(FALSE,8),TRUE),
    clip=c(0.1,2.5), 
    xlog=TRUE, 
    col=fpColors(box="royalblue",line="darkblue", summary="royalblue"))
```

HTH.

Comment: That works well, but now I have a new problem. I cannot position the graph between in between the case numbers and the ORs anymore using graph.pos = 4 (whereas before this was possible). I now get the following error if I want to change the position of the forestplot : Error in forestplot(tabletext, 
    cochrane_from_rmeta, graph.pos = 4,   : 
  The graph position must be between 1 and 2. You have provided the value '4'. Is there a way of changing the position of the plot?